# How to send data to a website service?

Tags: web-services, powershell

I'm trying to build a health check system of a group of application servers in PowerShell. I have 8 servers each running a different application which requires its own specific service to be running. I want this server to run a basic set of commands:

```
$RequiredServices = "Service1","Service2"
Get-Service -Name $RequiredServices | Select-Object name,status
Test-Connection -ComputerName $DomainController
```

I then would like to send this information to a local web service like SOAP or REST via XML or HTML, so I can get a quick snap shot of all of the application services on the web page. I can figure out the web page part, but I'm confused on the best method of sending this data to the web service? `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: @Raptor Thanks Raptor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the test results to the web service in the body of the request, here's an example of calling a web service passing the results in the body as json.

The body can represent any data structure you wish, below is just an example.

```
$Body = @{
    "TestName" = $TestName
    "Results" = @(
        @{
            "ServiceName" = $ServiceName
            "Status" = $Status
        }
    )
} | ConvertTo-Json

$contentType = "application/json"
Invoke-WebRequest -TimeoutSec $TimeoutSec `
                  -Method PUT `
                  -Uri $Uri `
                  -ContentType $contentType `
                  -UseBasicParsing `
                  -Body $Body
```

**Note**: 
If you are calling a rest api multiple times, you will need to clean up your connection, so you should top and tail the call with:

```
$ServicePoint = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::FindServicePoint($Uri)
# Make call here
$ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup("") | Out-Null
```

See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29863.powershell-rest-api-invoke-restmethod-gotcha.aspx) for more details.

As @Clijsters has pointed out [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) is another alternative over [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)

Comment: While your answer is imho comprehensive and goot, what would be the disadvantage of `Invoke-RestMethod`?

Comment: @Clijsters good point and valid question, I switched to Invoke-WebRequest as I was getting caught out by the issue described here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29863.powershell-rest-api-invoke-restmethod-gotcha.aspx
before finding that article at the time I thought Invoke-WebRequest wouldn't have the same issue, it turns out it does, but then I didn't go back to Invoke-RestMethod so either will work.

Comment: @DavidMartin Thank you for your response, I appreciate your help.